# How to add the two textbox value and pass to another textbox dynamically created textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Add the values of two textboxes and show the sum in another textbox, within a loop.

Code here:

```js
$('.common').change(function() {
  $('#id3').val(parseFloat("0" + $('#id1').val()) + parseFloat("0" + $('#id2').val()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="common" name="1" id="id1" value="">
<input class="common" name="2" id="id2" value="">
<input name="3" id="id3" value="" readonly>
```

I want to pass multiple times textbox value. Please check screenshot:

[image]

Thanks for help

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: Be sure to post your code in the question and/or link to jsfiddle, rather than posting a screen shot.

Comment: @shakti thanks for ask, i had same problem

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
$('.common').change(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $('.common').each(function(index) {
        if($(this).val()) {
            sum += parseFloat($(this).val());
        }
    });
    $('#sum').val(sum);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/theagitator/dz3bfL8k/1/

**EDIT:**
Notice that you have to add your own validation.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code snippet. Try it out:

```js
$('.equation').each(function(index, element) {
  element = $(element);
  element.find('.common').change(function() {
    var val1 = parseFloat(element.find('input[name="1"]').val());
    var val2 = parseFloat(element.find('input[name="2"]').val());
    element.find('input[name="3"]').val(val1 + val2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="equation">
  <input class="common" name="1" value="0" />
  <input class="common" name="2" value="0" />
  <input name="3" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div class="equation">
  <input class="common" name="1" value="0" />
  <input class="common" name="2" value="0" />
  <input name="3" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div class="equation">
  <input class="common" id="id1" value="0" />
  <input class="common" id="id2" value="0" />
  <input name="3" value="0" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
```

Comment: I agree. What is your point?  Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do?

Comment: If the textbox is within loop and i have to enter multiple times textbox value and get an another textbox.

Comment: I think I understand now.  Take a look at my revised answer and let me know what you think.

Comment: Yes, of course! I think this could be it. You just forgot to replace `id="id1"` with `name="1"` in the last `.equation`.

Comment: But it's not working on my page can you tell what's may be problem.I have also included library file oj jquery.

Comment: I can't tell you what your problem is unless I can see your code.  Can you post a jsfiddle?